# Get the Monitor sink of the current active output in PulseAudio

Tags: c, linux, pulseaudio

I am trying to record desktop audio using the simple API from libpulse. Audio playback works fine with the simple API, but what I need to do is:

Find the correct Monitor sink for the current active output to use it with `pa_simple_new` as `dev`.

Anyone some points I could check? E.g. enumerating devices?

Answer (score 0):

The monitor of a device is "device.monitor" (e.g. "Nullmodule01" -> "Nullmodule01.monitor"). Just append ".monitor" to the device name.